# how to Retrieve data from firebase using firebase UI

Tags: android

[image: My json data structure]

Can anyone help me to retrieve data from every child except doctor_profile.
Do i need to create separate class for every child or there is another way to solve this problem.
TIA

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235341/how-to-create-json-object-using-com-google-gson-class/45235660#45235660

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("addiction psychiatrist");

myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Psychiatrist psychiatrist = snapshot.getValue(Psychiatrist.class);

                    //now you can add it to your list (collection) or do what you want
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and of course you must have class which represents your objects, so for example:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Psychiatrist {

    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String hospital;

    public Psychiatrist() {
         // required empty constructor
    }

    public Psychiatrist(String name, String city, String hospital) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to create class for every child??

Comment: do others have the same fields (name, city, hospital)? if yes, then probably you can create one class for every child but you should add one more additional field which describes the type of the child (psychiatrist, cardiologist, ...). I hope you got the idea